# Industry practice of address sanitizer with vcpkg

Tags: c, cmake, vcpkg, address-sanitizer

I have authored a library with address sanitizer and "treating warnings as errors" configured in my CMakeLists.txt file

```
if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL 3.1 AND NOT WIN32) # sanitizer
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -fsanitize=address,undefined -fno-sanitize-recover=all")
    set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -fsanitize=address,undefined")
    # target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -fsanitize=address,undefined -fno-sanitize-recover=all)
    # target_link_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -fsanitize=address,undefined)
endif ()


if (CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC AND NOT WIN32) # werror
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Werror -Wall -ansi")
    # set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic")
    # target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -Werror -Wall -ansi)
    # target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic)
endif ()

option(BUILD_TESTS "Build Tests" ON) # Tests
if (BUILD_TESTS)
    enable_testing()
    include(CTest)

    add_subdirectory(test)
end if()
```

If you build your lib as a static lib with asan you need to build everything downstream with asan or at least link the asan libs.

As a result, the consumers of the library are also forced to link sanitizer with their builds.

### Question:

As a user I don't want to be enforced the compilation flags but then at the same time I need my library to be perfect and sanitized.

An idea occurred, how can I install the debug the version with sanitization but then release version without.

### Attempt 1

```
# Enable AddressSanitizer for Debug builds
if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug" AND NOT WIN32) # sanitizer
    message(STATUS "Applying AddressSanitizer for Debug build")
    target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -fsanitize=address,undefined -fno-sanitize-recover=all)
    target_link_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -fsanitize=address,undefined)
endif ()

if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug" AND CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC AND NOT WIN32) # werror
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Werror -Wall -ansi")
    # target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -Werror -Wall -ansi)
    # target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic)
endif ()
```

### Issue

As I consumed this library, and of course applying address sanitizer to my debug build in the consumer (reusing the same code block in my consumer), I still get asan errors. (implying both debug and release versions are applied address sanitizer)

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___asan_init", referenced from:
```

Comment: Imagine yourself as a user. What would you like?

Comment: Keep in mind that AddressSanitizer affects both the performance and memory usage of the program.

Comment: As a user I don't want to be enforced, but then at the same time I need my library to be perfect and sanitized. An idea occurred, how can I install the debug the version with sanitization but then release version without. Question updated.

Comment: I'm a developer. I decide to use your lib. I want it to have a minimal set of dependencies. If I pull your library in and it also needs lib X, Y and Z then I'll probably not use it. If it makes me change my compile and link lines then I probably won't use it. The sanitizer info is only useful to you - the library author and not people using your library.

Comment: @John3136 Makes sense. so I need to work out a strategy that sanitizer runs only if some OPTIONS are passed in my compilation and CI pipeline. With your comment it's obvious I have to remove sanitization from both debug and release versions.

Comment: I'm not a CMake wizard, but perhaps you could add additional targets like DebugSanitizer and ReleaseSanitizer, something like with how RelWithDebIfo works.

Comment: I moved and merged the sanitization under my conditional unit tests, to get things right in the development while my debug and release are lightweight and free of any dependencies. These comments have been helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments I have moved my sanitization under the test blocks.

```
option(BUILD_TESTS "Build Tests" ON) # Tests
if (BUILD_TESTS)

    if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL 3.1 AND NOT WIN32) # sanitizer
        set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -fsanitize=address,undefined -fno-sanitize-recover=all")
        set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -fsanitize=address,undefined")
        # target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -fsanitize=address,undefined -fno-sanitize-recover=all)
        # target_link_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -fsanitize=address,undefined)
    endif ()
    
    
    if (CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC AND NOT WIN32) # werror
        set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Werror -Wall -ansi")
        # set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic")
        # target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -Werror -Wall -ansi)
        # target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic)
    endif ()

    enable_testing()
    include(CTest)

    add_subdirectory(test)
end if()
```

This way both release and debug builds are lightweight free to any dependencies while I can assure quality in my local tests before making it available for delivery via VCPKG etc.